# Why Iskcon believe krishna is supreme and also follow Brahma-samhita without evidence?

Tags: vishnu, krishna

As I know Isckon devotes make the convince to the people through the help of the Brahma-samhita. 
And per my research (all vedas/purans/upnisad) I didn't find any valid proof of Brahma-samhita.It's not present in any scriptures. So, why they are trying to guide the people which has no evidence in scriptures.??!!

Now another thing they believe that Lord Narayan(Visnu) has lower quality than Lord Krishna.Lord Narayan is expansion of Lord Krishna.But I never find this type of thing in any Purans/uponisad.

There are 18 purans and each and every are created by sri vyasdev and they are divided in their particular modes.

**3 qualities**: truth, passion, and indifference.

**Sattva (Godness):** Vishnu Purana, Bhagavata Purana, Naradeya Purana, Garuda Purana, Padma Purana, Varaha Purana
**Rajas("passion"):** Brahmanda Purana, Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Markandeya Purana, Bhavishya Purana, Vamana Purana, Brahma Purana 
 **Tamas ("indifference"):** Matsya Purana, Kurma purana, Linga Purana, Shiva Purana, Skanda Purana, Agni Purana

And as we Pure Vaishnav we only accept the Sattva Modes of Scriptures.
So my point is that all sattva gun scriptures claimed and sing glories of Lord Narayan as Supreme. Why Iskcon try to misinterpreted the Scriptures to the people. I didn't find any evidence where it said like Lord Narayan is lower quality and he is expansion of Lord Krishna.

Another thing if you said like that he is expansion of Lord Krishna, then you are coming to the **Guru-sisya parampara, In your Parampara Naradmuni, vyasdeva and prahalad maharaj comes,** but they all are pure devotes of lord Narayan.
Naradmuni as per Narad Puran.
Vyasdeva is incarnation of lord Vishnu, which evidence is in Visnu-Sahstranam strotram.
Prahalad Maharaj is pure devote of lord Vishnu as described in Srimad -Bhagvatam.

And Iskcon's Devotes making fool to people in name of Brahma-samhita, which has no evidence.
and also misinterpreted the Scriptures as per their own speculation.

I believe that the Lord Krishna is the Supreme, but Lord Krishna is incarnation of the Lord Narayan, Lord Narayan came as Lord Krishna on the earth, so many scriptures are their which has this evidence.
Then why Iskcon making fool to discriminate the Lord Narayan from the Lord Krishna and telling people like different quality and everything.
It is not real knowledge ... they convince people on baseless scriptures, spread ignorance in people.
Devotion is doesn't exist Where discrimination comes.

So if anyone have some valid information about this then plz share with me.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  As currently posed, your post isn't really asking a question, it's just stating your view of ISKCON and their belief system.  If you want to turn your post into an actual question, like a question on why ISKCON people believe that Krishna is supreme, then edit it and flag me to reopen it.

Comment: @Keshav Perhaps one can address the Brahma Samhita part of the question like why only Gaudiya Parampara follows Brahma Samhita.

Comment: @surya : if you know regarding this tell me because no one have the answer of it .!!!

Comment: @Keshav I edited it ,and if you have an answer regarding this question then share with me..thanks

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Well, you shouldn't ask two separate things in the same question.  You should either ask why ISKCON believes Krishna is supreme, or you should ask why ISKCON people accept the Brahma Samhita.  And you should remove everything in the post where you're stating your own view.

Comment: It is because they have, probably, misinterpreted Bhagwad Geeta. I had this chance to go to Vrindavan Iskcon, and as a volunteer during Janmaashtami, i found their ways strange. They believe Bhakti yog is above KarmYog, they believe that fasting must, i repeat MUST, be performed (i wasn't well that time so argued with evidences from scriptures like Devi mahatamya that food is important), and most awkward, they firmly believe that women are distraction and one should not be in their company :0 So their ideology is corrupted, they are blindly followiny in what their Prabhupada said years ago.

Comment: I read so many books of prabhupada, I mostly found the sloka relevant to Vishnu/Narayan, but he translated like he put the name of Krishna instead of Vishnu/Narayan. and other most disgusting thing is he talked about Goloka, and its above from vaikutha, I never found Goloka is above from Vaikuntha in any scriptures, Yes Goloka is present but not above from Vaikuntha,and they think like their spamraday is best, but they don't know they are getting wrong knowledge, and the things is that if your Knowledge is not perfect then how can they reach to the bahktiyog ( Devotional Yog).

Comment: As you know to achieve bhaki-yog, we must also achieve Karma-yog and Gayan-yog. As per the Bhagvad-Gita. Any way I m gald you got a chance to debate their, but as you know they will never understand whatever we will put in front of them whether based on Scriptures or not.

Comment: We can just hope that the followers who truly are in search of the truth about Universe and life, get some good direction and the gyaan that Brahma-Vishnu-Mahesh are all the same, yet they do different karma for universe(their Karmayog), and this doesn't make one greater than the other. One needs to apply logic to understand religion, then only one can read scriptures for knowledge, be spiritual and lead a divine life :)

Comment: @ABcDexter: yes, brother. In our religion everybody try to show that their lord is bigger than yours and everything , and forget the aim of life, so this will not figure out in term of self-realization, we have to  understand scriptures with proper guidance. and achieve our goal. :-)

Comment: krishna is their isht-deva, so obvously  they will think him as bigger and rest of them as demi-god and subservient.